# How to get state value inside `this.state` object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, state

I have a stateful React Component, And i want to access a value of state  form inside the state object, specifically `number_rows`.

```
class Contracts extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      number_rows: 30, //starting default
      data: props.data
        .sort((a, b) => this.high_to_low(a, b, "latestVolume"))
        .slice(0, this.state.number_rows)
    };
  }
  render(){
    return(
      ...
    )
  }
}
export default Contracts;
```

I cant get my `slice()` to read the number of rows set in `this.state.number_rows`

example

```
b={a:'a', c:b.a}
{a: "a", c: "a"}
```

I tried `state.number_rows` and `this.number_rows`  Is this even possible? Is there a work around??

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: pass number_rows from parent component or store in redux. the way you're using is not right. and still you want to use same component then try with in componentDidMount method.

Comment: As @mfakhrusy was hinting at, I'm curious about how you expect `number_rows` to act.  Is it a constant or can it be changed? If it can, where in the hierarchy of React components does this happen?

Comment: Yeah `number_rows` will change, i it's not constant

Comment: you're accessing state before you've initialized it.

Comment: No, you cannot use it. Either make it a constant, or send it using props. I would do both if it is dynamic, something like this: .slice(0, props.number_rows ? props.number_rows : NUMBER_ROWS_CONSTANT);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numbers_rows` is a constant or may be changed?

If it's a constant, consider moving it out of your state since it's technically not the state of the application.

Perhaps do something like

const `NUMBERS_ROWS = 30;` above the `Contracts` component or save that variable inside your constants file(s) and import that variable on the component.

If it can be changed.

You can make your initial state of data to empty array, then you have 2 choice depending on your circumstances.

If `props.data` is a fetched value from an API, and the value can either be null or empty array if the fetching still in progress, use `componentDidUpdate` to update your `data` state according to `props.data` value after the value is already fetched.

If you're pretty sure the `props.data` won't be a null/empty array and already populated before the component is mounted, you can use `componentDidMount` to set the `data` state, basically you just move the logic of both sorting and slicing to either `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate` based on your circumstances.

Comment: 30 is just the starting default, i have a function to load more rows, which increases the number_rows state

Comment: Thanks @mfakhrusy this maybe the way to go.  Thanks everyone for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a default number rows variable to initialize your component's state first. After that, when you need to change your `number_rows` variable, just call the `alterNumberRows` function and calculate the `data` using the new `number_rows` value, and then update the state with the newly calculated `number_rows` and `data`.

```
class Contracts extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const DEFAULT_NUMBER_ROWS = 30;

        this.state = {
            number_rows: DEFAULT_NUMBER_ROWS, // starting default
            data: props.data
                .sort((a, b) => this.high_to_low(a, b, "latestVolume"))
                .slice(0, DEFAULT_NUMBER_ROWS),
        };
    }

    alterNumberRows = () => {
        // calculate the new number_rows
        // I just add one to the previous number_rows for simplicity
        const number_rows = this.state.number_rows + 1;

        // use the newly calculated number_rows to slice a new data array
        const data = this.props.data
            .sort((a, b) => this.high_to_low(a, b, "latestVolume"))
            .slice(0, number_rows);

        this.setState({
            number_rows,
            data,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            ...
        );
    }
}
```